# PayPal gateway has rejected request Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, error, paypal

I am using Magento 1.9 and I get this error when I click on PayPal method.

PayPal gateway has rejected the request. ReturnURL is invalid (#10471: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details). CancelURL is invalid (#10472: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).
Here is my site link: http://dashmarine.com/Index.php/
Here I have a product 'bike' (please search in that search field so you will find)

Maybe this Index.php is a problem because I can not remove this from url.
I tried to remove from backend but giving an error because rewrite module is not configured very well on my server. so hope this will not be a problem.

But Same PayPal account I integrate on another website which is from godaddy https://www.santebarley-uae.com/ is working very well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the default .htaccess file from Magento?

Comment: Yes m using .htaccess file. but my server is window server IIS

Comment: You are not using an htaccess file if you are using IIS. You are using web.config.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94048   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106296