# Payment has already been made for this InvoiceID (#10412: Duplicate invoice)

Tags: paypal, invoice, recurring

I have created one recurring profile product & using paypal as payment gateway.
After clicking on payment I got the error as

> "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Payment has already been made
>   for this InvoiceID (#10412: Duplicate invoice)."

I have done the required settings in my paypal account. **PayPal Account (standard) > Profile > Payment Receiving Preferences > Under Block accidental payments**: select **No, allow multiple payments per invoice ID**.

But still it is giving me the same error.

Any suggestion will help a lot.

Comment: Check step by screenshots, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/error-10412-paypal-duplicate-invoice-php/

Answer (score 10):

I think, this issue accrues when we have multiple instance of website. In case you have multiple development instance of website. You need to allow "Accept Duplicate Invoice" from Paypal.

In order to fix that you will need to go to your PayPal account, My Account > Profile > My Selling Tools > Credit Card Statement Name > "Allow multiple payments per invoice ID".

Comment: Thanks its working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should clean `var/session` folder and try again.

**WARNING** This might be destructive, see comments

Comment: this could be a comment.

Comment: This needs a big warning sign, that it logs out all customers and removes all carts of guest visitors. Also, why would it help?

Comment: When I encountered this problem it is the first that helped me. When you leave your customer at unfinished  checkout, in customer session is already created InvoiceID for him. Any attempt to carry out the following checkout lead to this error message. This is the first that comes to mind

Comment: Although this solution worked for me as well (on a testing site, luckily), I must stress the comment made by @FabianSchmengler as well. A less destructive solution would be preferable but if you really need a fix this would do the job.